# Show the row from a search result - Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to make a search function that displays the entire row from matching entries.

This is what currently happens using: `=IFERROR(IF(B3="","No Results",ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(DOCS!C2:C, SEARCH(B3, DOCS!C2:C)))),"No Results")`

[image: 0]

And this is the column I am trying to show

[image: 0]

Example

Data:

- Fortnite,Video Game,Epic Games
- PUBG,Video Game,IDK
- Steam,Service,Valve
- Amazon,Service,Amazon
- Cats,Species,Animal Kingdom

Search Column B for "Service"

(MY CURRENT RESULTS):

- Service
- Service

(MY INTENDED RESULTS):

- Steam,Service,Valve
- Amazon,Service,Amazon

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hN2bKUGATssF9uqrfktRemH8L8q2Rlxe5HFETZRzifE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D1<>"", IFERROR(FILTER(A:A, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A:A), LOWER(D1))), "No Results"), )
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=FILTER(DOCS!A2:G, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(DOCS!C2:C), LOWER(J1)), DOCS!E2:E="active")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hN2bKUGATssF9uqrfktRemH8L8q2Rlxe5HFETZRzifE/edit?usp=sharing